# How to hide folders list in the title bar?

Tags: sublimetext3, titlebar

At this moment in title bar of Sublime Text 3, except full path to the file, I'm currently working with, there is list of all folders I have opened in Sublime Text 3.

There are only 4 folders, and such list in parentheses already wasting space.
IMHO, it's useless feature and I'm interested if there is way to hide this list in title bar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any direct way of hiding the folder names, but you can minimize the space taken up in the title bar by making a 1-character project. Click on **`Project -> Save Project As...`** and name it something like `A.sublime-project` or whatever. Now, instead of this:

[image: No project]

You get this:

[image: project]

It's not perfect, but it'll help clean things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But sorry, it can't be solution. Hope developer will see this question and consider it as feature in settings for next release.